# Is there way to use environment variables in build pipelines for scheduled builds?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

```
schedules:
- cron: "${cron_schedule_value}"
  displayName: Test
  branches:
  include:
  - master
always: true
```

I'd like to use something like this but didn't find examples. Is it possible to use env variables as cron value?

Comment: Tested myself. It seems that we can not use env variables as cron value.

Answer (score 1):

probably not, because this is not being handled by the agent, but, rather, by Azure Devops itself. so there are no environment variable available at `expansion` time.